# Task 'shadowJar' not found in root project 'papercontract'

Tags: gradle

I get an error when I install the chaincode in digibank.
peer lifecycle chaincode install cp.tar.gz

Commercial Paper（java）

```
Welcome to Gradle 5.6.2!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Groovy compilation
 - Groovy compile avoidance
 - Test fixtures for Java projects
 - Manage plugin versions via settings script

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'shadowJar' not found in root project 'papercontract'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 7s
```

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else faced this issue , rename shadow-build.gradle to build.gradle and try package and install command again.